# Laravel - nested relationships through Many to Many

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a setup with parents and their children. A child can have multiple parents and each child can be assigned multiple messages by the system. Each parent can also have multiple children.

I already have an instance of the user: $parent. Now I would like to receive all the posts that belong to this parent's children. Laravel's "has many through" does not work with many-to-many relationships.

At the moment I solved it with a custom method, but I'm looking for cleaner ways of resolving this issue.

This is my setup:

**User (parents)**:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Child', 'parents_children', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
class Child extends Eloquent
{
    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'parents_children', 'child_id');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Posts', 'ChildPost');
    }
}
```

**Posts**

```
class ChildPost extends Eloquent
{
    public function child()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Child');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this, but it looks like there's no "baked in" solution for has many through many to many

Answer (score 0):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with support for `BelongsToMany`: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function childPosts() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(ChildPost::class, ['parents_children', Child::class]);
    }
}
```